# Rails displaying multiple same records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am providing my active records below. In view/users/show I want to display any project the user is working on, through blueprints. When a user adds multiple blueprints to a project, the project is showing up multiple times. I tried some validate_uniqueness options to no avail.

```
class Blueprint < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :id, :name, :project_id, :user_id, :loc
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :comments
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :id, :name
  has_many :blueprints
  has_many :users, :through => :blueprints
  has_many :comments
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :id, :name
  has_many :blueprints
  has_many :projects, :through => :blueprints
end
```

Here is the view code that is displaying multiple values of the same project.

```
    <% @user.blueprints.each do |blueprint| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to blueprint.project.name, project_path(blueprint.project) %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `uniq` option to `true` in user's `projects` relation like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects, :through => :blueprints, :uniq => true
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. When moving further, I went to fix the same problem on the other end and realized I accidentally left in your fix when I added cgat's solution. It took both of you to help my noobness!

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have the projects association in the User, why don't you loop through the user's projects instead of the blueprints.

```
<% @user.projects.each do |project| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to project.name, project_path(project) %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: Worked!Now I will spend some time examining why this gave me so much trouble :?

Comment: You were looping through blueprints, thus, for each blueprint the user had, one link would be produced, even if that link is the same thing over and over again. When you write `has_many :projects, through: :blueprints` you are telling rails that you only want the projects of that user, and in order to figure out what projects the user has, look through the blueprints table. Hope that helps clarify things

Comment: It does. I am curious why I did that in the first place. Thanks for your help.